How to show related posts based on tags
I want to show similar posts on the post page using this code:
$tagsArray = array_map('trim', explode(',', $tags));

$tagsString = '';

foreach ($tagsArray as $tag) {
    $tagsString .= "tags LIKE '%{$tag}%' OR ";
}

$tagsString = rtrim($tagsString, 'OR ');

$data = array(
    'id' => $id,
);

$sql = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM ps_objects WHERE id != :id AND {$tagsString} ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 5;");
$sql->execute($data);
$result = $sql->fetchAll(); 

The problem is that the post which has one tag for example john are shown all posts which have tags john or john,Leo,Mike but on the page of the post which has several tags for example john,Leo is not shown anything and should be shown all posts where there is at least one tag john or Leo in any sequence.
Help to write such SQL
Trying FIND_IN_SET didn't help.

Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad? - yep, it is - and this is one of the many reasons why. Your query would be simpler if your data was stored in a proper format in your database. Learn the basics of relational database design and normalisation. A many-to-many relationship like this should be represented by a link table between a posts list and a tags list.

Issue of the sub-optimal data structure aside - looks like you forgot to properly wrap your tag conditions into braces. WHERE id != ... AND tags LIKE ... OR tags LIKE ..., and WHERE id != ... AND (tags LIKE ... OR tags LIKE ...) are two very different conditions.

Here's how you can rewrite your SQL query.
$tagsArray = array_map('trim', explode(',', $tags));

$placeholders = implode(', ', array_fill(0, count($tagsArray), '?'));

$data = array_merge([$id], $tagsArray);

$sql = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM ps_objects WHERE id != ? AND (". implode(' OR ', array_fill(0, count($tagsArray), 'FIND_IN_SET(?, tags) > 0')) .") ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 5;");
$sql->execute($data);
$result = $sql->fetchAll(); 

